# How to print first 10 natural numbers who's square is divisible by 5?

Tags: ruby, functional-programming

I am looking at this slideshow at the moment:
http://www.slideshare.net/GeisonFlores/ruby-functional-programming

Slide 24 shows that I can find the first 10 natural numbers who's square is divisible by 5 by doing this:

```
Integer::natural.select{ |x| x**2 % 5 == 0}.take(10).inject(:+)
```

I get the error: cannot find type 'natural' for Integer.
I have tried to using ruby 1.9.3 and 2.2 and can't seem to run this LOC.

Can anyone point me to how I can correct this?
I am new to FP.

Comment: You don't actually need to do the squaring - a number's square is divisible by 5 if and only if the number itself is divisible by 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Integer::natural` is defined on other slide. Run this code before executing the `select`:

```
class Integer
 def self.natural
   Enumerator.new do |yielder|
    (1..1.0/0).each do |number|
     yielder.yield number
    end
   end
 end
end
```

Comment: Which slide is that? I couldn't find it.

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/tokland/source/browse/trunk/functional/presentation/functional-ruby.txt?r=684